# Resources for video with only dialogue or a guide track

Tags: dialogue

I'm searching for some media to practice with. Rather than designing sound directly for an entirely quiet trailer for example I want to work with some dialogue and or location recordings to prepare some show reel that includes some more subtle mixing and and editing as well as bombastic designed trailers. Does anyone have any direction for a question like this? I will accept a private link to the material as well if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of videos and older films on Archive.org.  I'm sure you could find a good variety on there.

Answer (score 0):

if you are interested in animation i have a tip.
during my study sound design is used this website http://www.animationmentor.com/ 
animators could upload their animation for a dialogue only sequence from a particular movie. i don't know if it still allows download but i made good use of it in 2004.

there was another site called something like '40secondsanimation', but i can't find a link..

arnoud

Comment: ah i found the other site google "11 second club"